# R: How to determine sequence patterns and frequency

Tags: r, events, sequence, analysis

The data represents countable events.  The goal is to identify all the sequences of independent parameters that precede a dependent parameter, and also determine if the sequences generate a false positive, the dependent parameter is zero.

To start, I'm just trying to generate the frequency for an independent variable preceding a dependent variable, or preceding a null dependent variable.

This generates some random counting data, dep is the dependent variable, and indp1-5 are the independent variables.

```
# Data sequence frequency analysis

library(data.table)
set.seed(13)
Ns=20
dtab<-data.table(dep = sample(0:3,Ns,prob=c(3,2,1,.5),replace=TRUE),
               indp1 = sample(0:3,Ns,prob=c(5,2,1,.5),replace=TRUE ),
               indp2 = sample(0:3,Ns,prob=c(5,2,1,.5),replace=TRUE ),
               indp3 = sample(0:3,Ns,prob=c(5,2,1,.5),replace=TRUE ),
               indp4 = sample(0:3,Ns,prob=c(5,2,1,.5),replace=TRUE ),
               indp5 = sample(0:3,Ns,prob=c(5,2,1,.5),replace=TRUE ))
```

Locate the rows that have a null dependent variable, and tabulate the sum of the lag occurrences of the independent variables.  The sample data was generated by hand by changing the value for jlag.

```
ir <- which(dtab$dep == 0)
jlag=4; colSums(dtab[ir[ir>(jlag+1)]-jlag,])
# Desired result

#   dep = 0, lag sums
#     lag  indp1 indp2 indp3 indp4 indp5 
#       0      3     6    10     2     3 
#       1      6     4     9     2     5
#       2      2     4     4     3     6
#       3      2     7     5     2     6
#       4      1     4     6     0     0
```

Locate the rows that have a non zero dependent variable, and tabulate the sum of the lag occurrences of the independent variables.  Again, the sample data was generated by hand by changing the value for jlag.

```
ir <- which(dtab$dep > 0)
jlag=4; colSums(dtab[ir[ir>(jlag+1)]-jlag,])
# Desired result

#   dep = 0, lag sums
#     lag  indp1 indp2 indp3 indp4 indp5 
#       0      7    13     6     5    10
#       1      4    15     6     5     7
#       2      5    12    10     2     4
#       3      5     7     9     3     3
#       4      5    10     8     5     9
```

I'm looking for suggestions on how to identify sequences of events.  I'm starting by trying to estimate the probability that an independent event occurred before the dependent event, and the probability than an independent event occurred before a null dependent event.

The sequences of independent variables can be extracted with

```
dtab.seq <- dtab[,2:6,with=FALSE]
seq_matrix = unique(dtab.seq)
```

The transition matrix can be generated from a map from dtab.seq into row indices of seq_matrix, and then just calculate the transition matrix from the frequency table of the vector offset.

```
seq_matrix_rows  <- apply(dtab.seq,1,
             function(xx){
               which(apply(seq_matrix,1,function(x){all(x==xx)}))
             })

trans_mat <- table(seq_matrix_rows[1:(nrow(dtab.seq)-1)],
                   seq_matrix_rows[2:nrow(dtab.seq)])
```

This would plot the transition matrix

```
library(Matrix)
image(trans_mat)
trans_mat[1:10,1:10]
```

The dependent transition matrix is easier since the dependent variable is integers

```
dep_trans_mat <- table(dtab$dep,
                         seq_matrix_rows)
```

I think that provides the sequence patterns, sequence frequencies, sequence (state) transition matrix, and the sequence / dependent transition matrix.

Comment: Why are you using a data table but not using data table syntax?

Comment: I'm still not used to data table syntax....